# Is it possible to have callback for amp-lightbox

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to have callback for lightbox? I have a form in lightbox and want to autofocus it but it does not work by html autofocus attribute. So I want to catch the event then the lightbox is visible and programatically focus it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any documentation regarding autofocus in amp-lightbox. What have you tried so far? Can you post your code to help you better?

Comment: I have no solution yet!!!